# Best way to render a single Rmd file using blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

We have a set of Rmd reports that live in a "knowledge repository" that we render via blogdown.

We'd like to facilitate someone rendering a single report. Is there a best way to do this using blogdown?

If not, what about adding a `files` argument to `render`, such that the specified files are rendered (and if not specified, defaults to the current behavior)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the internal (i.e. not exported) function `blogdown:::build_rmds()`, e.g.,

```
blogdown:::build_rmds('content/foo.Rmd')
```

This will generate `content/foo.html`. If you have already started `blogdown::serve_site()`, your site should be automatically rebuilt, otherwise you can manually run `blogdown::hugo_build()`.